# azure backup- error during enabling

Tags: backup, azure, cloud-storage

I can't enable Azure backup on some my VMs in Azure. I have already virtual machines migrated from classic to ARM, but disks for a few one are still stored in Classic storage. If I try to enable backup I receive error "Deployment to resource group 'ResourceGroupName' failed." "Write ProtectedItems Failed" I also can't migrate this disk to ARM using standard migration procedure.
On new machines or corrected migrated I can enable Azure backup without any problems.

thanks for any help

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to migrate to ARM?

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix, migrate the storage too.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview#migration-of-storage-accounts

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know- storage migration is a solution :) but I get some errors during migration process. I migrated all environment and commit this process but one classic storage account finish with errors. OK, I was hoping that there is some tricky operation. I will retry next days. Thanks